# Как динамически создавать обработчики на angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Вот есть функция, в которой добавляется элемент:

```
 $scope.processCreateInfo = function(event, process){
  $('.maintext').append('<a class="greenbtn createbtn waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="processCreate()">Запустить процесс</a>');
 }
```

Однако, функция processCreate не отрабатывает, когда кликаем на новый элемент

```
$scope.processCreate = function(){
    alert(1)
}
```

Comment: может стоит определиться все-таки jQuery или angular? при смешивании как попало ничего хорошего не получится

Comment: а как на angular тогда?

Comment: все зависит от задачи. В ангуляре основанием являются данные, в данном случае непонятно что и зачем. Просто в лоб можно решить используя массив по которому с помощью ng-repeat выводить эти ссылки внутри _maintext_? а по кнопке _processCreateInfo_ просто добавлять элемент в массив, все остальное сделает ангуляр

Comment: var wrap = angular.element('.maintext');
    angular.element(wrap).append('<a class="greenbtn createbtn waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="processCreate(' + id + ')">Запустить процесс</a>');

пытался так, кнопку добавляет, но событие не отрабатывает

Comment: и что это? :-) могу сказать, что данный код так же не сработает и _processCreate_ не будет запускаться

Comment: он не запускает processCreate, и не могу понять почему, хотя элемент добавлен

Comment: Стоит сначала определиться, **что конкретно** нужно сделать, задавая вопросы не относящиеся к задаче, можно очень долго ходить вокруг и так и не прийти к простому решению

Comment: Когда я кликаю на одну из кнопок ng-click="processCreateInfo()" эта кнопка должна создать другую кнопку передав ей id (так как все кнопки processCreateInfo пронумерованы) 

По факту должно быть так:
'<a class="" ng-click="processCreate(' + id + ')">Запустить процесс</a>'

Comment: Это помогло: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11780658/4918275

Comment: сделай [mcve], например на [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) или [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) чтобы можно было запустить и посмотреть, по твоим вопросам абсолютно непонятно, что ты пытаешься сделать, но видно что ты делаешь это абсолютно не правильно :)

Comment: Не стоит использовать этот сервис, когда можно обойтись без него

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жизненный цикл приложения на ангуляре весьма сложен.

Нельзя просто добавить разметку, чтобы сработали все плюсы ангуляра, вроде two-way binding, Необходимо эту разметку **скомпилировать**.

В большинстве случаев хватает встроенных возможностей ангуляра, конкретно в случае из вопроса, не нужен ни jQuery, ни вставка с помощью *angular.element*, что, по сути, тот же самый jQuery, только обрезанный.

1. Нужно определиться, что должно быть в итоге: список ссылок
2. список может изменяться

Список - это массив данных, для изменения массива можно использовать например метод `push`, добавляя в него нужные данные. В данном случае, так как неизвестно что именно нужно, пускай данными будет порядковый номер элемента.

В итоге для изменения списка в обработчике кнопки нужно добавить в него что-то, например

```
$scope.processCreateInfo = function(event, process){
    $scope.data.push($scope.data.length);
}
```

Осталось дело за выводом: здесь поможет директива [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Запустить процесс

И все вместе:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [];
    $scope.processCreateInfo = function(event, process) {
      $scope.data.push($scope.data.length);
    };
    $scope.processCreate = function(num) {
      console.log(num);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="processCreateInfo()" />
  <div class="maintext">
    <div ng-repeat="num in data">
      <a class="greenbtn createbtn waves-effect waves-light btn" ng-click="processCreate(num)">Запустить процесс {{num}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, вы лучший)